# Coverage: Which test touched this line?

Tags: python, coverage.py

Up to now the coverage in Python binary: A line was executed or not.

Is there a way to get per python code line a  lists of tests which execute this line?

I read the coverage docs, but could not find a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

coverage.py can do this, with [dynamic contexts](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/contexts.html#dynamic-contexts)

Clearly I need to make this easier to find.  What would have helped?

Comment: 'Context' is not intuitive for me, nor is "dynamic context", so I would have the  same difficulty as OP.  Add a switch “what-test-ran-this-line”  to the CLI.  It's a feature that many would want, so make it very easy to do

Comment: I've added to the docs in two places: https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/commit/22fe2eb167a18dda8fd3e14cbf9166a1c7331fb9

Comment: This answer would be better if it showed how to use the library to perform the action the the question...

Answer (score 1):

While there is documentation about how to get a list of tests, which cover a certain line of code, both for

- [coverage.py](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.5/contexts.html) and
- [pytest-cov](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contexts.html)

the feature is kinda "obfuscated" by the name `dynamic contexts`. Also, the current documentation is written in a way, that at least I could not easily understand.

That is why I had a look at different configuration files of projects, from which I knew they use this feature, and wrote a [blog post about this topic](https://jugmac00.github.io/blog/enrich-test-coverage-with-contexts/).

I hope this is a good starter!

And then, let's try to make the documentation easier to discover and easier to understand for everybody.

Comment: Thoughts? https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/commit/22fe2eb167a18dda8fd3e14cbf9166a1c7331fb9

Comment: That's great! Thanks, Ned!

Comment: Note: pytest-cov **uses** coverage.py's _dynamic-contexts_ feature.